# How to transfer data from a desktop pc to a USB flash drive?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, usb, desktop, flash

On a windows 10 Home Edition desktop pc how do i transfer data Firefox browsing history to a USB flash drive? I see a lot of how-to's on the web, but they don't tell me exactly on how to do it.

They lack the right details on them or are clashy and inconsistent on what they are describing or are not explaining clearly in their instructions on how to do it.

Comment: Have you tried copying the Firefox user profile?  It's located within the appropriate folder in `%LocalAppData%`.  We do not provide private help so you can remove your email address.

Comment: Your question is totally misleading being not sufficiently specific. Nobody else will find a possible answer inside because one has to assume that you just got a new computer and that you do not know how to handle an USB flash drive.

Your issue is primarily about exporting the browsing history!

Answer (score 1):

1. On your menu of Firefox click it then click on help
   [image: h1]
2. Then click on "More Troubleshooting information"
   This will open another tab on your browser

[image: h2]

3. Scroll down abit and you should find this "Profile Foder", click on "Open Folder" it should open the the folder where your profile is stored

[image: h3]

4. Once the folder is open go back a little, click on the "Roaming" or click on the up arrow until you find it, Should be 4 clicks to get there

[image: h4]

5. Click on the Mozilla folder, right click then copy, and now you are ready to paste your folder on your USB

[image: h5]

Once you pasted this folder you can now move it to a new pc or have it as a backup of your navigation data.

If you want to paste the folder in a new PC, close your firefox first
then just open you Start menu and type this `%appdata%`
it should open the Roaming folder

[image: 6]

Once there locate the Mozilla folder rename it to something like
"mozilla_bkp"

And then paste your folder form your USB.

Hope it helps.

More info here [Back up and restore information in Firefox profiles](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/back-and-restore-information-firefox-profiles)